# Category Tree In WooCommerce Product API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I can retrieve product cat id from api, and then can call again Category API to retrieve category parents. But I am just asking, is there any way I can display category tree in product API?

Comment: The WooCommerce API is not the same API as the WordPress REST API, so this question would be off topic here. You'll need to ask in a forum that accepts WooCommerce questions. That being said, I believe the answer is no. Usually that sort of thing is the client's job.